# IE 11 displays CSS differently from other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element, internet-explorer-11

I've got this project that I'm working on, and it's displaying differently in different browsers (imagine that). The CSS works fine in every browser I've tried (chrome, safari, firefox) except for IE11 (again, imagine that). Here's a picture of the IE version:

[image]

Here's what it's ***supposed*** to look like:

[image]

Now, I've looked through the dev tools on both Chrome and IE, and here's the results.

IE:

[image]

Chrome:
[image]

So, as you can see in the picture, in IE, the `bwizard-steps button::before` and `bwizard-steps button::after` are marked out, yet they are working as intended in Chrome.

Any ideas why this would be? I've looked it up, and IE11 is supposed to support the `::before` and `::after` tags. Yet it is clearly ignoring them. I've even tried going into compatibility mode for IE, and that just looks even worse.

Comment: IE doesn't render things properly... What else is new? :)

Comment: In your IE screenshot of the dev tools, is there something above those rules that is overriding the ones shown?

Comment: @ginovva320: I've gone through the tools, deleting anything that may override the rules I want, and there's nothing overriding them at all.

Comment: Is it just me or do you have `button` tags as direct descendants of `ul` tags?  Is that legal HTML markup?

Comment: IE10+ has gone from one extreme to the other with regard to standards compliance. Validate your code.

Comment: Just wondering: what if you tell the button -ms-appearance: none; ? Can you give the CSS part please ?

Comment: As @nzifnab says, you should have li as ul children. May be try wrapping your buttons in li ?

Comment: Yep, that's likely to solve the problem.  IE tends to have undefined behavior when your markup is wonky.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, IE does not render it incorrectly at all.

Comment: @vals: I've wrapped my buttons in `<li>` tags, and they are no longer horizontal, but vertical buttons.

Comment: Well you'll have to update your CSS accordingly, to account for the new markup.

Comment: @nzifnab exact ! change button for li

Comment: In addition to be using lists in the wrong way, you are also using positionabsolute unnecessarily. One tip is as you create your HTML, you try to validate it using the following link: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Well, this is an inherited project. So all the code was written before my time. Not to mention that the W3C validator doesn't validate local HTML, and I can't push to the production site. But I will look more into what you and nzifnab have said.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Ctrl+S in page on WebBrowser, save as HTML document, after send by upload in: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload I know that changing a system ready is something difficult (and sometimes a waste of time), but really the html is flawed. This will be your personal decision unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

I have had similar problem.

Solution that worked for me was giving the button `overflow: visible;`

Working example (IE9+): http://jsfiddle.net/aBfF8/1/

Comment: Bounty started. In a day you'll have meaningless internet points!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely that you have `button` tags as direct descendants of `ul` tags.  In valid HTML markup, the only direct children of a `ul` should be `li`.

You should wrap you buttons in `li` tags - but then you're going to have to make some CSS changes so that your list items aren't vertical.  `float: left;` on them among other changes to make them appear the way you want.

Edit:  I can provide a better-detailed solution of exact improvements you can make if you provide me with the appropriate HTML and CSS (ideally in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))